# linq vs sql (or .NET app vs SQL Server management studio)

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a linq query that retrieves rows from a View based on an id column (where id=@id)

This query takes 4 seconds to run.  I have used SQL Server Profiler to inspect the query that is executed by linq, and if i copy that query directly to management studio and execute, the query only takes 56ms.

This exponential time increase is consistent across all linq queries to views in my application.  What could be causing this extended execution time in my (WPF) application when the same queries execute < 100ms ?

**== EDIT ==**

I've managed to isolate further, comments show profiler duration;

```
/* 3953ms, 111487 reads */
context.SkuView.Where(p => p.TermId == 35 && !p.IsDeleted).ToList(); 

/* 90ms, 173 reads */
context.SkuView.Where(p => p.TermId == 35).ToList();
```

If i paste the (sql rendered) linq queries directly into ssms i get;

```
/* 250ms, 173 reads */
SELECT * FROM SkuView WHERE TermId == 35 AND IsDeleted = 0

/* 250ms, 173 reads */
SELECT * FROM SkuView WHERE TermId == 35
```

So the problem has something to do with the read count through linq when using !p.IsDeleted...

Comment: Wow, that's a huge time difference. To be clear, the 4 seconds to run is the time it takes the query to execute according to SQL Profiler?

Comment: correct.  linq executes the query using exec sp_executesql, and profiler shows 4second run time.  if i copy that exact exec _sp_executesql that just ran, and execute it in SSMS, profiler shows 58ms

Comment: L2S isn't the most efficient way of querying a DB, but thats a pretty massive difference.

Comment: I'm not surprised that there is an increase in time, but two orders of magnitude is a shock. There has to be something that you're not telling us.

Comment: Looking at the query runtime isn't going to help. Have you looked at the execution plan in SSMS? It's hard to say anything from what you've given us. Could be network latency. Could be the user you're impersonating. Or the way you setup your connection string. etc etc etc

Comment: What is the IsDeleted column type in the DB, and what ColumnAttribute does it have in the linq mapping?

Comment: @Remus bit NOT NULL mapped to bool

Comment: System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Name = "IsDeleted", Storage = "_isDeleted", DbType = "bit NOT NULL", CanBeNull = false)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible culprits are:

- contention. When run from Linq, other application activities are locking rows and thuse causing the query to stall waiting for locks. When run from SSMS, there is no other activity and thus the query finishes fast.
- difference in parameter types. Passing a NVARCHAR parameter for a comparing against a VARCHAR column results in a full scan (index cannot be used due to [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) rules). This is caused by wrong LINQ ColumnAttribute. When run from SSMS the query is usualy copied incorectly and the parameter type is changed to VARCHAR.
- cold run vs. warm run. Query is run by LINq first and this warms up the cache (fetches the data from disk to memory). When run again from SSMS there is no wait for IO.

In any case, the tools to investigate are all at your disposal.

- compare the number of Reads from the two queries ([RPC:Complete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175543.aspx), [TSQL:BatchComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176010.aspx) events in Profiler)
- compare the plans. Use [Showplan XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189318.aspx) event.
- look at what is the LINq query *doing*: [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx) wait_type, wait_time and wait_resource columns
- compare the query stats for the two cases: [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx). things to look for are large diferences between the two cases in logical_reads and physical_reads, indicative of wildly different plans (scan vs. seek), or wild differences in elapsed_time but similar worker_time (indicative of blocking, locks likely).

Comment: thanks Remus. As per the edit above, reads are huge on the affected query.  trying to pull showplan xml out of profiler atm.  Assuming the execution plan is different, any pointers on how to fix that?

Comment: try to post the plan. Original plan XML, not the graphic rendering. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179321.aspx

Comment: execution plans are radically different;  long query; http://pastebin.com/kqTMKCdz short query; http://pastebin.com/f7difnj6

Comment: The long plan is using nested loops, the short one uses hash joins. But since you do have a fast plan XML now, rather than trying to understand the difference I would recommend using a plan guide and see if the Linq query picks up the 'good' plan. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189854.aspx

Comment: I see you fixed the issue by updating stats. I would still recommend deploying a plan guide so that the query does not suddenly decgrade later in production due to, again, bad stats.

Comment: For those courious about why hash joins are so much faster: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/08/10/687630.aspx

Comment: Great advice Remus, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

updating statistics on the db fixed this issue.

```
exec sp_updatestats
```

Much thanks to [Remus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105929/remus-rusanu) for the learning ;)

Comment: this is only a temporary fix.  adding/changing data will slowly cause  execution plans to again degrade.

Answer (score 0):

> This query takes 4 seconds to run... if i copy that query directly to management studio and execute, the query only takes 56ms.

There's no magical difference between your application and management studio.  Both programs create a connection to the database and issue sql text commands (once inside the database server: a query plan is generated, IO and CPU is spent and results transmitted back).  Since the only difference here is "app making a connection", you should inspect the connections.  Start with the connection strings...

Assuming no problem in the connection string, move on to [SET settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx).  In particular [SET ANSI_NULLS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) should be on, as it can interfere with computed columns and views with clustered indexes.

Answer (score 0):

[ARITHABORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190306.aspx) is ON by default in SSMS and OFF by default for a SqlClient connection.

This solved a similar issue for me:

```
new SqlCommand("SET ARITHABORT ON", connection).ExecuteNonQuery();
```